# How to detect android phone 3G On Off events

Tags: java, android, events, mobile, 3g

I am writing an android application that handles 3G usage .. 
When the user turn on the 3G Mobile Data Connection , I want to calculate the elapsed time of 3G usage and notify the user when the elapsed time comes to a specific time..

The problem is I don't know how to detect the 3G On Off events in order to run certain codes when those events occur. 
Please help me with a detailed example as
I am a beginner to android.

I have tried googling for it but does not help me. 
I would like to call a function like this one:

```
     public void function on3GOnCallback(){
                // i will start counting the time here
     }
     public void function 0n3GOffCallback(){
              // `i will stop counting the time here `
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

System level callbacks are implemented using [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)s. Please refer [Android BroadcastReceiver Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) for more info.

The events for mobile data state are broadcast by [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html). In particular, you seem to be interested in [`TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#DATA_CONNECTED) and [`TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#DATA_DISCONNECTED) events. You can distinguish between the different types of data networks (2G, EDGE, 3G, etc) by querying the network type of the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).